# Determining a relation involving a greater than and less than condition

Tags: relations

Can anyone offer guidance on how to determine the following relation as being reflexive, symmetric or antisymmetric when the relation is given by

$$ x \sim y \iff (x - y) > 0 \land (x - y) < 4. $$

I think it is not reflexive and antisymmetric.

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a relation, $\sim$, on some set $A$ is reflexive if, and only if,

$$x\sim x \quad \forall x\in A$$

and is antisymmetric if, and only if,

$$\forall x,y\in A, \quad x\sim y \quad \land \quad y\sim x \implies x=y$$

Showing that your relation is not reflexive should be straight forward (is $x-x > 0$?).

Showing antisymmetry for your relation would be difficult (since it isn't) and to show this, can you find any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x-y >0$, $x-y < 4$ and $x\neq y$?

Additionally, is it symmetric? This requires that if $x\sim y$ then $y\sim x$. That is, can you show that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ where $x-y >0$ and $x-y < 4$, is $y-x >0$ and $y-x <4$?

Comment: Ok... x - x > 0 cannot be the case. So I'm correct in thinking this is irreflexive. Many thanks.

Comment: And neither symmetric or antisymmetric?

Comment: Yes, this relation is not antisymmetric and is not symmetric.